# Find $x$: $5\cos(x) = 2\sec(x)-3$

Tags: trigonometry

This was the last question on my exam and it's driving me nuts the answer has to be in degrees

$5\cos(x) = 2\sec(x)-3$

$5\cos^2(x)/2 = -3$

$\cos^2(x) = -6/5$

Since $-6/5$ is negative

The answer $\sqrt{\cos^2(x)}$ could not be correct

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your second line. It should be

$$5\cos^2 x=2-3\cos x$$

You now have a quadratic equation in $\cos x$: solve for it, then solve for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$5\cos x-2\sec x\not=\frac{5\cos^2x}{2}$$and that$$5\cos x-2\sec x=5\cos x-\frac{2}{\cos x}=\frac{5\cos^2x-2}{\cos x}$$
So, you should have
$$\frac{5\cos^2 x-2}{\cos x}=-3,$$
i.e.$$5\cos^2x-2=-3\cos x.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: How did you get -3 next to cos???

Comment: @BrandonJerz: What I did is just the following : $5\cos x=2\sec x-3\Rightarrow 5\cos x-2\sec x=-3\Rightarrow \frac{5\cos^2x-2}{\cos x}=-3\Rightarrow 5\cos^2x-2=-3\cos x$. At the last step, you can multiply the both sides by $\cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your algebra:
$$
5\cos x=\frac{2}{\cos x}-3
$$
Then you can multiply both sides by $\cos x$:
$$
5\cos^2x=\cos x\left(\frac{2}{\cos x}-3\right)
$$
You get something quite different from your equation $5\cos^2x/2=-3$, don't you?